# Persist ViewModel data from GET to POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel, asp.net-4.0

I have 2 action methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Customize()
{
  return View(new CustomizeViewModel { Thing1 = "test", Thing2 = "test" });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Customize(CustomizeViewModel customizeViewModel)
{
  _someService.DoSomething(customizeViewModel);

  ...
}
```

My ViewModel looks like:

```
public class CustomizeViewModel
{
  public string Thing1 { get; set; }
  public string Thing2 { get; set; }
  public string Thing3 { get; set; }
}
```

In my View, I have a textbox that collects a value for `Thing3` and simply shows the values for `Thing1` and `Thing2`.  My problem is, when I POST and enter the POST version of the `Customize` method, I only get a value for `Thing3` (the one that I typed into the textbox.)  Is there any way to get the values I populated in the GET version of the Customize method to carry over?  I tried `UpdateModel()` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the things for which hidden input fields were created.  Store the values in there using `HiddenFor` in the View and you should be set.  The only data that will come along for the ride in the HTTP POST version are form-input elements.

Answer (score 1):

Add hidden fields for Thing1 and Thing2.